# How to open a Python 3.x instance in LabVIEW2016?

Tags: python, labview

For research purposes I have written a script in Python 3, and now this method should be included into the production cycle, which is running LabVIEW2016.

The script takes a matrix corresponding to a grayscale image and a float as command line arguments and prints a float after doing some image processing. Timing this with `cProfile`/`snakeviz` reveals that invoking the script takes around 1 second - 90% of this however is taken up by importing `numpy` and functions from `cv2` and `scikit-image`. This is crucial, because running this via command line from LabVIEW thousands of times is simply too slow. How can I avoid doing the imports every single time?

- The Python node in LabVIEW only exists from LabVIEW2018 onwards, and upgrading is out of the question at the moment
- [Python Integration Toolkit](http://docs.enthought.com/python-for-LabVIEW/) doesn't offer any new licences since it is end of life
- [LabPython](https://labpython.sourceforge.net/) is very old and only available for Python 2

My next thought was to incorporate some precompiled version of the script, but that doesn't work with the command line arguments.

Is there some way to call a Python 3 script with inputs from LabVIEW2016 without having to run the imports every single time?

Comment: I have zero experience with this, but I would consider the following options: 1. Reimplement the code in LV. 2. Run the compiled version and use TCP to communicate between the two programs instead of command line arguments.

Comment: What @Yair said, but you could also consider giving the Python code a web API, e.g. using Flask, and using the LabVIEW [HTTP Client VIs](https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview/page/lvcomm/http_client.html) to access it.

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions. Right now production is testing a version compiled with [nuitka](https://nuitka.net/), but if that doesn't cut it, I will try out your ideas.